# How to model ferrofluid - water interaction correctly?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

The system I am trying to model is essentially moving water interacts with ferrofluid. The ferrofluid is in a box that contains air and ferrofluid, such that the setup is buoyant. The ferrofluid chamber has outlets so that it can interact with water. Here's an example image of the system:

[image]

I need confirmation in these aspects:

1. That the right choice here is to model it like two phase flow not single phase or mixing model.
2. That it can be modelled by either level set method or moving mesh method without compromises in results.
3. If I do not want the fluids to mix, is there a way to still maintain pressure balance between them? Would a semi-permeable membrane work here? If not, is there any other way?

Comment: For #2, there may be separate difficulties in writing the code required for one method versus the other, but if they both solve the PDE(s) you are interested in, I cannot fathom why either would "compromise" the results.

Comment: The ferrofluid I had was water soluble; in fact, i had to extract water from it to make it work properly. It consited basically out of the nanoparticles suspended in water. If you take semipermeable membranes, the pressure of the ferrofluid against it surroundings will be higher then the water pressure due to its osmotic pressure.

Comment: @sir_khorneflakes Do you know of ferrofluids that are not water soluble (It's been difficult finding exact names online)

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks! I assume that means point 1 is right.

Comment: @LuciferHolmes
https://ferrofluid.ferrotec.com/products/ferrofluid-emg/oil/ This shows oil based ferrofluid exists

Comment: @LuciferHolmes I think my comment on #2 is independent of #1. That said, my understanding of the mixing model is that is still a multiphase model.

Comment: @sir_khorneflakes Thanks!

Comment: @KyleKanos Right.